# How to select the immediate lower off-diagonal elements of a square numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, diagonal

I have a square numpy array which only has non-zero values along the diagonal

```
a = 
array([[a_0_0 , 0. , 0. , ..., 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , a_1_1 , 0. , ..., 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , a_2_2 , ..., 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       ...,
       [0. , 0. , 0. , ..., a_n-2_n-2 , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , ..., 0. , a_n-1_n-1 , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , ..., 0. , 0. , a_n_n]])
```

I want to select all the elements to the immediate lower left of the diagonal, i.e. where i = j + 1 so I can insert values:

```
a[lower_indices] = b  # how do i get lower_indices?
a = 
array([[a_0_0 , 0. , 0. , ..., 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [-b_1_0 , a_1_1 , 0. , ..., 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , -b_2_1, a_2_2 , ..., 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       ...,
       [0. , 0. , 0. , ..., a_n-2_n-2 , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , ..., -b_n-1_n-2, a_n-1_n-1 , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , ..., 0. , -b_n_n-1 , a_n_n ]])
```

Is there a fast way to do this?

Comment: did you check `numpy.tril_indices` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html

Comment: Yep I'm aware of the `triu` and `tril` functions. But in this case, I only want the immediate off diagonals, not all the indices for the lower triangle.

Comment: oh did not see that, then, in that case, it will be a much simpler solution which you have already found!

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found was this

```
row_idx = np.arange(1, a.shape[0])
col_idx = np.arange(a.shape[0] - 1)
a[row_idx, col_idx] = b
```